# Mootools morph to class not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, mootools

So i'm using this following Mootools Class i made to animate my header menu its mainly using the morph effect.

Too see check the following link in google Chrome or Firefox http://proclef.geantduweb.ca/

I have another site with the same problem. The animation is a little diffrent but its based from the same code.

http://raanm.geantduweb.ca

In internet explorer: I do not obtain any console errors and the rest of the javascript runs fine.

Any ideas ? Im stump... i tryied a Tween... but morph to class seems to be the best options

Thanks

```
var gdwMainmenu = new Class({
    options: {
        author:         'Géant du web - MB',
        updatedby:  'Géant du web - Jonathan Robidas',
        version:        '1.3',
        lastUpdate: '2014-10-03'
    },
    Implements: [Options,Events],
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.setOptions(options);
        if ($('header')) {
            this.mainmenu           = $('header');
            this.placeholder    = $('mainmenuplaceholder');

            this.effect_header = new Fx.Morph('header', {
                duration: 500,
                transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
            });
            this.effect_logo = new Fx.Morph('logoimg', {
                duration: 1000,
                transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
            });
            this.effect_table1 = new Fx.Morph('table1', {
                duration: 500,
                transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
            });
            this.effect_table2 = new Fx.Morph('table2', {
                duration: 500,
                transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
            });
            this.scrollFix();
            window.addEvent('scroll', this.scrollFix.bind(this));
        }
    },
    scrollFix: function() {
        var sp = window.getScroll().y-20;
        var wp = $('header').getSize().y-40;

        if (sp > wp) {
            this.setToFixed();
        } else {
            this.setToNotFixed();
        }
    },  //End of scrollFix()
    setToFixed : function() {
        if (!this.mainmenu.hasClass('active-fixed')) {
            this.mainmenu.addClass('active-fixed');
            this.placeholder.addClass('active-fixed');

            //Image then container
            this.effect_logo.pause();
            this.effect_logo.start('#header.isFixedImg').chain(function() {
                this.effect_header.pause();
                this.effect_header.start('#header.isFixed');

                this.effect_table1.pause();
                this.effect_table1.start('#header.noWidth1');

                this.effect_table2.pause();
                this.effect_table2.start('#header.fullWidth2');

            }.bind(this));
        }
    },  //End of setToFixed()
    setToNotFixed : function() {
        if (this.mainmenu.hasClass('active-fixed')) {
            this.mainmenu.removeClass('active-fixed');
            this.placeholder.removeClass('active-fixed');

            //Container first then image
            this.effect_header.pause();
            this.effect_header.start('#header.notFixed').chain(function() {
                this.effect_logo.pause();
                this.effect_logo.start('#header.notFixedImg');

                this.effect_table1.pause();
                this.effect_table1.start('#header.fullWidth1');
                this.effect_table2.pause();
                this.effect_table2.start('#header.noWidth2');
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }   //End of setToNotFixed()
});
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    if ($('header')) {
        var menuFixed = new gdwMainmenu();
    }
});
```

Comment: One of the important updates of the new 1.5 version of MooTools is removing Browser sniffing and with that a fix for IE11 that changed the UA string. Did you try using MooTools 1.5.1? The change should be compatible.

Comment: Oh, and please describe what is the failing behavior. I mean what should the animation look like.

Comment: Well the header is full expanded when the user is at the top of the page Otherwise the header animates to a Smaller version (see google chrome or firefox where it works already)

Comment: ill try mootools 1.5.1 tho. i believe Joomla comes with 1.4

Comment: i just replaced mootools 1.4 to 1.5 http://proclef.geantduweb.ca/media/system/js/mootools-core.js still nopt working in IE and still working in chome/firefox

Comment: I just updated mootools more to 1.5 as well and same result. i wish i had an error message or something to go on...

Comment: likely a CSS parser issue. you are asking it to parse the CSS rules and morph the properties it finds. this means there needs to be a default origin value as well as a target one. for this kind of site, you are better off using animate.css (http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for effects/transitions and a scrollspy. add / takeaway classes. avoid computational javascript. having said that, even though your code is not great, can't spot any glaring problems. you need to set breakpoints in Fx.Morph to see what it extracts and ensure it has started the code path.